# If I roll $4$ dice and you roll $5$, what is the probability that you roll more $6$s than me?

Tags: probability

I got the question a "If I roll $4$ ordinary six-sided dice, and you roll $5$, what is the probability that you roll more $6$s than me?"

I answered it and got $0.3683$ using the binomial coefficient and a spreadsheet.

Earlier, I was given the same question, only both people had $6$ dice, and the answer I got was $0.3415$. It strikes me as odd as the difference is only about $0.02$, despite the fact that one person is rolling more dice. Are my calculations correct? Is it simply because in the $0.3415$ question they are rolling more dice?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider two cases:

$1)$ after $4$ die rolls  you had obtained more $6s$ of him, therefore the last die roll is useless because also your opponent obtains a $6$, you win equally.

$2)$ after $4$ die rolls you are in a draw( obtained the same number of $6$), he has to obtain a $6$ to win.

In the first case the probability is $0,5$ in the second case is $ \frac{1}{6}$